# How can I choose a time at first and use it for all the days in vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am collecting the working hours from user. Now the user need to select time for each day. It will be time consuming for them. So, make them choose a time first and use that time for all the days selected. If he need to change time for a particular, make him to do that.

This is the first time i am asking a question in stack overflow. I am using the following code for my project now.

```
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Working Hours :</label>
     <div v-for="value in day" class="checkboxFour"<input type="checkbox" id="need" value="value.val" v-model="value.selected" style="width: 10%!important;">
<p>FROM</p>
     <label for="need" style=" width: 20%!important;">{{value.name}}</label>
          <input id="value.from" type="time" v-model="value.from" name="value.from" style="width: 30%!important;">
<p>TO</p>
       <input id="value.to" type="time" v-model="value.to" name="value.to" style="width: 30%!important;">
        <br>

      </div>
    </div>
```

When I use this code. I need to choose time for each day I am ticking on the checkbox.

My vue js code for the same is

```
work = new Vue({
el: "#work",
  data: {
   data: [],
    day:[
    {name:"Sunday",val:1},
    {name:"Monday",val:2},
    {name:"Tuesday",val:3},
    {name:"Wednesday",val:4},
    {name:"Thursday",val:5},
    {name:"Friday",val:6},
    {name:"Saturday",val:7}
    ],
    string:'',
  },



methods: {
     wrkSubmit: function(e) {
    var arr = [];
    this.day.map(function(v,i) {
     console.log(v.selected == true,);
     if(v.selected == true) 
      {
      arr.push(v.val+'&'+v.from+'&'+v.to);
      }
    });
    this.string = arr.join(',');
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['wrk_list'] = this.string;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/workhour/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {
                alert("Success")
            }
              else {
               alert(" Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
},
   }
```

So, how can I improve the code, so that user need to add time once and choose that time for all the days selected. Also make him to change time if, the working hour is different for a particular day?

Please help me to find out a solution for the same..
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Make a component to represent a Day, that receives the default time values as props. As data items, it has a boolean for whether to use the default values, and values for `from` and `to` to use if it's not using the defaults.

```js
work = new Vue({
      el: "#work",
      data: {
        defaultWorkingHours: {
          from: null,
          to: null
        },
        day: [{
            name: "Sunday",
            val: 1
          },
          {
            name: "Monday",
            val: 2
          },
          {
            name: "Tuesday",
            val: 3
          },
          {
            name: "Wednesday",
            val: 4
          },
          {
            name: "Thursday",
            val: 5
          },
          {
            name: "Friday",
            val: 6
          },
          {
            name: "Saturday",
            val: 7
          }
        ],
        components: {
          dayComponent: {
            template: "#day-template",
            props: ['name', 'val', 'defaultFrom', 'defaultTo'],
            data() {
              return {
                useDefaultTimes: true,
                from: null,
                to: null
              };
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="work">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Working Hours :</label>
    <label>
      From
      <input type="time" v-model="defaultWorkingHours.from">
    </label>
    <label>
      To
      <input type="time" v-model="defaultWorkingHours.to">
    </label>
    <div v-for="d in day" class="checkboxFour">
      <day-component :name="d.name" :val="d.val" :default-from="defaultWorkingHours.from" :default-to="defaultWorkingHours.to"></day-component>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="day-template">
  <div>
    {{name}}
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="useDefaultTimes">
    <label>
      FROM
      <template v-if="useDefaultTimes">
        <input :value="defaultFrom" name="value.from" disabled>
      </template>
<template v-else>
        <input type="time" v-model="from" name="value.from">
      </template>
</label>
<label>
      FROM
      <template v-if="useDefaultTimes">
        <input :value="defaultTo" name="value.to" disabled>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <input type="time" v-model="to" name="value.to">
      </template>
    </label>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: hello sir,, how can it be possible to change

Comment: Change what? Did you run the snippet?

Comment: I've updated the `day` object to match yours. It should work just like your form fields.

Comment: checkboxes are not loading